# very slow to show result

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I have a Windows7 system with Wamp 2.4 running this simple php code

```
for ($year = 2004; $year <= 2015; $year++){
    for ($month = 1; $month <=12; $month++){
        mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT sum(Weight) FROM Lab WHERE YEAR(date)=$year  AND MONTH(date)= $month") or die(mysql_error());

        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $weight = $rows['sum(Weight)'];
            ${'mes'.$month}=$weight;
            $weight3=$weight+$weight3;
            $weight=0;
        }
    }

    Echo $year, " Total - ", $weight3, "<br>";
    Echo $mes1, ", ", $mes2, ", ", $mes3, ", ", $mes4, ", ", $mes5, ", ", $mes6, ", ", $mes7, ", ", $mes8, ", ", $mes9, ", ", $mes10, ", ", $mes11, ", ", $mes12, "<br>";
    $weight3=0;
}
```

My database is about 400000 rows and for some reason it takes about 40 seconds to shows any result. If I do the same query (year by year) in mysql it takes less than a second.

Is there anything wrong with my code that slowsdown the query? or is this a Wamp related problem?

Thanks for any help!

Final code

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT year(date), month(date), sum(Weight)
FROM Lab
WHERE date BETWEEN '2004-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
GROUP BY year(date), month(date)");
   while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo $rows ['year(date)']," ", $rows ['month(date)']," ",$rows['sum(Weight)'];
       Echo "<br>";
   }
```

Comment: I don't think you need to connect to the database each time. You should get it out of your loop. That would be a start

Comment: Is MySQL on a separate server? or is it local? Plus what @Unex said, don't loop the connection. Also `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: That query won't work. You have a syntax error `YEAR(date=`

Comment: Jens I missed the ")"... fixed...thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code is incredibly inefficient. You connect to the DB 11 years * 12months = 132 times. The loops are unecessary too. Why not just do it all in the query?

```
SELECT year(datefield), month(datefield), sum(weight)
FROM youtable
WHERE datefield BETWEEN '2004-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
GROUP BY year(datefield), month(datefield)
```

Comment: yes, this is the best way to improve performance in this case

Comment: Thanks, removing the connection to outside the loop and using your query did help a lot. About  1 second now.